# IOS - How to avoid keyboard from hiding when uiwebview reloads

Tags: iphone, ios, webview, keyboard, hide

I have a webview that loads a web chat client.

As every chat, the page has a textfield to input text.

The problem is that when the user opens the keyboard it is automatically hidden after a short time due to several ajax requests that are reloading the page. This becomes really annoying for the user as he or she can't input a complete sentence before the keyboard hides.

I don't know why, this only happens in iPhone 4S and iPhone 5. In iPhone 4, 3GS, and Simulator everything works ok.

I have tried to use **shouldStartLoadWithRequest** to catch the request and load it after the user hides the keyboard, but this ruins the chat session.

I tried to "hang" the request with a Thread sleep in the same method, but it happens in the Main Thread so it freezes the entire application.

Is there a way I can simply avoid the keyboard from hiding?

Answer (score 7):

So after a long research I found a way to do it, its not the best but it helped me a lot.

First use `DOM` to check if the webView firstResonder

```
- (BOOL)isWebViewFirstResponder
{
    NSString *str = [self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.activeElement.tagName"];
    if([[str lowercaseString]isEqualToString:@"input"]) {
        return YES;
    }
    return NO;
}
```

Then respond to `UIWebViewDelegate` method `shouldStartLoadWithRequest`, and return `NO` if `UIWebView` is first responder

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
    if([self isWebViewFirstResponder] &&
   navigationType != UIWebViewNavigationTypeFormSubmitted) {
        return NO;
    } else {
        return YES;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think guys in ShareKit should do this for "SHKOAuthView.h".
I met this problem while authorising to tumblr.

Comment: Hi @NaloikoEugene make sure to also check &&
       navigationType != UIWebViewNavigationTypeFormSubmitted in case the user taps done

Comment: Had the exact same issue when authorising Tumblr, your fix helped me a lot, thanks @Basheer_CAD :)

Comment: I had some problems with this solution on a page with lot of frames but adding [self.webView stopLoading]; in shouldStartLoadWithRequest before returning NO seem to improve it.

Answer (score -1):

You can use Notification center inside your DidLoad method to listen when the keyboard will hide like this:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                     selector:@selector(keyboardWillHide)
                                         name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification
                                       object:nil];

- (void) keyboardWillHide{

  [webView becomeFirstResponder];
}
```

which will make the web view first responder and show the keyboard again. I haven't tried it myself so hopefully it will do the trick..

Comment: you are fixing the problem by the same problem. This is wrong

Answer (score -1):

if your text field is on UIView

You can use web view Delegate method

```
-(void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    [textField becomeFirstResponder];
}
-(void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    [textField becomeFirstResponder];
}
```

otherwise if textField is on UIWebView then replace textField with webView as shown below.

```
-(void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    [webView becomeFirstResponder];
}
-(void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    [webView becomeFirstResponder];
}
```

Comment: this will not answer the question. you are showing and hiding the keyboard every time after loading, which is not correct